# PHP file error on opening in Aptana Studio

Tags: php, aptana

I cannot open a .php file in Aptana studio editor, it gives me this error:

> Could not open the editor: Input must be CoreBrowserEditorInput

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you googled it? Since I've found some pages relevant to your post.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the software - you should post this on their support forums.

Comment: It might be an error based-on Eclipse. Since Aptana is eclipse-based. Still I wonder why you encountered this error. Try to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the current editor you opening php file. Use "Open With > PHP Editor" context menu action on a file.

Cheers,
Max